# Dictionary to .csv file

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

Can't seem to figure this out.
I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
sorted_metrics = {
    "1-Aug-2017": {"Messaged":1,"Rejected":2}
    "2-Aug-2017": {"Messaged":3,"Rejected":2}
    "3-Aug-2017": {"Messaged":4,"Rejected":2}
    "4-Aug-2017": {"Messaged":2,"Rejected":2}
    "5-Aug-2017": {"Messaged":3,"Rejected":2}
    "6-Aug-2017": {"Messaged":1,"Rejected":2}
    "7-Aug-2017": {"Messaged":5,"Rejected":2}
    "8-Aug-2017": {"Messaged":0,"Rejected":2}
    "9-Aug-2017": {"Messaged":4,"Rejected":2}
}
```

I want my .csv file to look likes this:

```
Date         Messaged    Rejected
1-Aug-2017   1           2
2-Aug-2017   3           2
3-Aug-2017   4           2
4-Aug-2017   2           2
5-Aug-2017   3           2
6-Aug-2017   1           2
7-Aug-2017   5           2
8-Aug-2017   0           2
9-Aug-2017   4           2
```

csv.writerow either puts each character in a column or I can't concatenate the information into a single row.

Comment: Please show what you have tried so that can be clarified.

Comment: The `csv` module does not handle data in your format. You are going to have to force the sequence/dict you pass to `writerow`... seems pretty straight-forward, no? Just `key, value['Messaged'], value['Rejected']`. As an aside, you probably should be using a named-tuple as a record type, instead of a nested `dict`

Comment: it seems if I do it like that, the datetime string is not in a single column but every character is in a seperate column.

Comment: Then I suspect you are inappropriately calling `list` on the `key` somewhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv


sorted_metrics = {'1-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 1, 'Rejected': 2},
                  '2-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 3, 'Rejected': 2},
                  '3-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 4, 'Rejected': 2},
                  '4-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 2, 'Rejected': 2},
                  '5-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 3, 'Rejected': 2},
                  '6-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 1, 'Rejected': 2},
                  '7-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 5, 'Rejected': 2},
                  '8-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 0, 'Rejected': 2},
                  '9-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 4, 'Rejected': 2}}

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter="\t", lineterminator="\n", fieldnames=['Date', 'Messaged', 'Rejected'])
    writer.writeheader()
    for k in sorted_metrics:
        d = {'Date': k}
        d.update(sorted_metrics.get(k))
        writer.writerow(d)

print(open('output.txt').read())

# Date    Messaged    Rejected
# 1-Aug-2017  1   2
# 2-Aug-2017  3   2
# 3-Aug-2017  4   2
# 4-Aug-2017  2   2
# 5-Aug-2017  3   2
# 6-Aug-2017  1   2
# 7-Aug-2017  5   2
# 8-Aug-2017  0   2
# 9-Aug-2017  4   2
```

Feel free to change the `delimiter` and `lineterminator` parameters to match your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

Overall, here's what you need:

```
l = [[k, v['Messaged'], v['Rejected']] for k,v in sorted_metrics.items()]
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Date','Messaged','Rejected'])
        writer.writerows(l)
```

---

### Detailed explanation:

1- You can start by converting the dictionary to a list of lists

```
In [31]: sorted_metrics
Out[31]: 
{'1-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 1, 'Rejected': 2},
 '2-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 3, 'Rejected': 2},
 '3-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 4, 'Rejected': 2},
 '4-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 2, 'Rejected': 2},
 '5-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 3, 'Rejected': 2},
 '6-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 1, 'Rejected': 2},
 '7-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 5, 'Rejected': 2},
 '8-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 0, 'Rejected': 2},
 '9-Aug-2017': {'Messaged': 4, 'Rejected': 2}}

In [32]: 

In [32]: l = [[k, v['Messaged'], v['Rejected']] for k,v in sorted_metrics.items()]

In [33]: l
Out[33]: 
[['9-Aug-2017', 4, 2],
 ['2-Aug-2017', 3, 2],
 ['6-Aug-2017', 1, 2],
 ['3-Aug-2017', 4, 2],
 ['4-Aug-2017', 2, 2],
 ['1-Aug-2017', 1, 2],
 ['7-Aug-2017', 5, 2],
 ['8-Aug-2017', 0, 2],
 ['5-Aug-2017', 3, 2]]
```

2- Then write to a csv as follows:

```
with open("output.csv", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(['Date','Messaged','Rejected'])
        writer.writerows(l)
```

---

output:

```
Date,Messaged,Rejected
9-Aug-2017,4,2
2-Aug-2017,3,2
6-Aug-2017,1,2
3-Aug-2017,4,2
4-Aug-2017,2,2
1-Aug-2017,1,2
7-Aug-2017,5,2
8-Aug-2017,0,2
5-Aug-2017,3,2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to use `pandas`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sorted_metrics).T
df.index.name = 'Date'
df.to_csv('bla.csv', sep=' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

`for key1, value1 in sorted_metrics.iteritems():
    for key2, value2 in value1.iteritems():
        #do something`

This iterates through the dictionary, giving you access to all the data, I leave it up to you to properly handle that data.